# Weblogic JMS Message Purge using Date time Timestamp

Tags: timestamp, weblogic, purge

Can anyone suggest how to delete/ purge JMS Message using date or within date in Weblogic 11g

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you want to do it with JAVA, WLST or WebLogic Admin Console but the general steps would be:

1. Build JMS Message Selector that uses JMSTimestamp header (value needs to be in EPOCH format)
2. Invoke deleteMessages operation with your JMS Message Selector on JMS Destination of your interest